# Count the blank line in the column with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to see how many data is empty in ITEM column.

I can find the number of lines filled with the following code. But I need to be empty...

index. html.erb

@users.coult(:item)

Tanks.

Comment: Have you tried something like: `@users.where(item: nil).count`? Assuming "blank" and "empty" mean "nil".

Comment: Yes, I tried it now and it worked. Thank you very much

Comment: Great. Added as an answer for you to upvote/accept if it suits you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it should be:

```
@users.where(item: nil).count
```